# Can I tell which process is using my 3G connection?

Tags: internet, 3g, mobile-broadband, hsdpa

My PAYG 3G bandwidth is vanishing at an alarming rate. Yesterday 2GB just surfing and processing email, in an hour or two. I just experienced it again, with 500MB over about an hour. I suspect either my network is ripping me off, or I have unseen downloads taking place. How do I see those downloads?

Comment: windows/application auto updates? `netstat -b` on Windows, from an elevated prompt tells you which processes are using your network, and where they are connected. simple, but might help.